# I can't get multiple inputs to display in my text area

Tags: java, swing

I've written a 308 line pizza GUI for a homework assignment due in a few days. I've tested everything and the code works (kind of).

My problem is that I ask a user to select the toppings they want on each pizza, the size and the pizza type, the user then adds their selections to a cart and they are prompted to add another pizza or check out.

If the user checks out the data is displayed as:

```
Your Order Number: 1
Pizza Type: Thin Crust
Pizza Size: Medium
Toppings: Cheese, Green Peppers
Total $11.50

Your Receipt:
Subtotal: $11.50
Tax: $1.06
Amount Due: $12.56
```

That's the correct output. The problem occurs when the user selects more than one pizza. If the user selects two pizzas, then only the most recent pizza is recorded. Thus, the print out message would say "Your Order Number 2", but it wouldn't include order #1. I want the display to display ALL orders. I've tried a few different things and I think my issue has to deal with `ordertext`, but I'm not 100 percent sure.

I've added a small portion below and I am hoping someone can spot what I am missing.

```
    // Creating the "Pizza Type" radiobutton grid
    VBox gridForRadioButtons2 = new VBox(20);
    gridForRadioButtons2.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5)); 
    gridForRadioButtons2.setStyle
      ("2px; -fx-border-color: red");
    Text PTtext = new Text("Pizza Type");
    PTtext.setFill (Color.RED);
    RadioButton rbTC = new RadioButton("Thin Crust");
    RadioButton rbMC = new RadioButton("Medium Crust");
    RadioButton rbP = new RadioButton("Pan");
    gridForRadioButtons2.getChildren().addAll(PTtext, rbTC, rbMC, rbP);
    grid.add(gridForRadioButtons2, 2, 1);

        ToggleGroup group2 = new ToggleGroup();
        rbTC.setToggleGroup(group2);
        rbMC.setToggleGroup(group2);
        rbP.setToggleGroup(group2);

    // Create a new text area
    TextArea orderscreen = new TextArea();
    orderscreen.setPrefColumnCount(25);
    orderscreen.setPrefRowCount(7);    
    grid.add(orderscreen, 0, 4);


        btnAC.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        String mytoppings = "";
        double mytopcost = 0.0;

            // Processing button logic & checkboxes logic
            if (chkTom.isSelected()) {
                mytoppings = mytoppings + "Tomato "; // Topping
                mytopcost += 1.50; // price
            }

            if (chkGP.isSelected()) {
                mytoppings = mytoppings + "Green Peppers "; // Topping
                mytopcost += 1.50; // pice
            }

            if (chkBO.isSelected()) {
                mytoppings = mytoppings + "Black Olives "; // Topping
                mytopcost += 1.50; // pice
            }

            if (chkMR.isSelected()) {
                mytoppings = mytoppings + "MushRooms "; // Topping
                mytopcost += 1.50; // pice
            }

            if (chkEC.isSelected()) {
                mytoppings = mytoppings + "Extra Cheese "; // Topping
                mytopcost += 1.50; // pice
            }

            if (chkPep.isSelected()) {
                mytoppings = mytoppings + "Peppeoni "; // Topping
                mytopcost += 1.50; // pice
            }

            if (chkSS.isSelected()) {
                mytoppings = mytoppings + "Sausage "; // Topping
                mytopcost += 1.50; // pice

            }
            if (mytoppings.length() < 2)
            {mytoppings = mytoppings + "no toppings selected";}


        // Pizza Types logic
        String mypizzatype = "";

            if (rbTC.isSelected()) {
                mypizzatype = mypizzatype + "Thin Crust "; // Type
            }

            if (rbMC.isSelected()) {
                mypizzatype = mypizzatype + "Medium Crust "; // Type
            }

            if (rbP.isSelected()) {
                mypizzatype = mypizzatype + "Pan "; // Type
            }

        // Pizza Sizes logic
        String mypizzasize = "";
        Double smpzcost = 6.50;
        Double mdpzcost = 8.50;
        Double lgpzcost = 10.00;

            if (rbSM.isSelected()) {
                mypizzasize = mypizzasize + "Small "; // Pizza Type
                order = smpzcost;
            }

            if (rbMD.isSelected()) {
                mypizzasize = mypizzasize + "Medium "; // Pizza Type
                order = mdpzcost;
            }

            if (rbLG.isSelected()) {
                mypizzasize = mypizzasize + "Large "; // Pizza Type
                order = lgpzcost;
            }

        // Storing the order text
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            ordertext = "Your Order Number: "
                    + numberPizzas
                    + "\nPizza Type: " + mypizzatype
                    + "\nPizza Size: " + mypizzasize
                    + "\nToppings: " + mytoppings
                    + "\nTotal: $" +  df.format(order + mytopcost)
                    + "\n";
            total = (order + mytopcost);
            numberPizzas++;
            pizzas = pizzas + total;

            // Display order text
            orderscreen.setText(ordertext);
    });


    btnAddPizza.setOnAction(e -> {
        chkTom.setSelected(false);
        chkGP.setSelected(false);
        chkBO.setSelected(false);
        chkMR.setSelected(false);
        chkEC.setSelected(false);
        chkPep.setSelected(false);
        chkSS.setSelected(false);
        chkMR.setSelected(false);
        rbSM.setSelected(false);
        rbMD.setSelected(false);
        rbLG.setSelected(false);
        rbTC.setSelected(false);
        rbMC.setSelected(false);
        rbP.setSelected(false);
    });

            btnChkOut.setOnAction(e -> {
        // Storing the order text
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                tax = pizzas*.0925;
        tax = pizzas *.0925;
        subtotal = pizzas + tax;
              ordertext =   ("Your Receipt: "
                      + "\nSubtotal: " + df.format(pizzas)
                      + "\nSales Tax: " + df.format(tax)
                      + "\nAmount Due: " + df.format(subtotal)
                      + "\n");

              // Display order text
              orderscreen.setText(ordertext);
    });



    primaryStage.setTitle("Justin's Pizza Palace Shop");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
```

Comment: How are you storing your "pizzas"? I see logic for one pizza, where do multiple(s) come in?

Comment: At the top double pizzas;

Comment: AH!! I just figured it out